# GA query parameters breaking link

Tags: google-analytics

I'm working on this site k-west.co.uk - if you go to the footer and click the link to Twitter you'll find it doesn't work. Google Analytics has added utm parameters and it seems this breaks Twitter. If you remove the paramters from the url, Twitter works.

How can I tell Google Analytics not to add query parameters to this link? Is there a class or attribute I can add that will do this?

I tried to remove the parameters using JavaScript but as GA only adds the parameters as you click the button, I cannot remove them, I need to prevent GA adding them in the first place.

Thanks

Comment: I suspect you have auto link tracking set in your GA tag within GTM. This was probably set to send GA parameters along as users navigate to the third-party booking engine. It looks like in this case auto linking has been configured to work on **all** outbound links. It should be configured so it only works on links to the third party booking engine.

Answer (score 2):

It looks that you're using Google Tag Manager to add Google Analytics functionality to your site and cross-domain tracking is enabled for Analytics tag. But it looks misconfigured as @vinoaj suggested. You need to modify your Google Analytics settings variable to only add cross-domain parameters to the links to target site:
[image]
While Auto Links Domain field is blank all the links will be extended with cross-domain tracking parameters.